Most efficient way to slice a large concatenated array in Javascript?
I need to retrieve at most N elements from an API endpoint, but this endpoint is paginated, with no options to configure how many items I get per page. The elements are json objects.
The obvious solution is this:
let page = 1
let totalAmount = 0
let elements = []
while (totalAmount < N) {
  const pageElements = apiService.getElements(page)
  elements.push(...pageElements)
  totalAmount += pageElements.length
  page += 1
  //code for the case when N is bigger than all the elements in the API
}

elements = elements.slice(0, N)

But this is probably too inefficient when N is big, since slice makes a copy of the array in memory.
So, what I'm doing is, inside the while loop, checking if I'm in the last iteration, and if I am, I slice only that page:
if (totalAmount + pageElements.length > N) {
  pageElements= pageElements.slice(0, N - totalAmount)
}

Is there a way to make this even more efficiently? The second solution is probably efficient enough, but I really need to make this as good as possible.

You can just do elements.length = N;, you don't need to slice it.

You can also do pageElements.length = N - totalAmount on the last iteration.

Yes, I think elements.length = N is the best solution, I forgot you could do that.

No need to make a copy, you can change the length of an array in place.
if (totalAmount + pageElements.length > N) {
  pageElements.length = N - totalAmount
}


Nice, I forgot you can set the length to be honest, but in that case wouldn't it be better to do it for the whole concatenated array? So just do elements.length = N, it would avoid checking each iteration, and would make the code more readable.

Sure, it just means you do a little unnecessary copying on the last segment when you concatenate. it's a minor difference.
